# Cannot get main function to compile in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compilation, program-entry-point

I am relatively new to Haskell and everything I have done has been completed through GHCi, however, now I am trying to compile using GHC, however, I constantly get the error message `The IO action ‘main’ is not defined in module ‘Main’`, I have tried declaring `main = do`, however, I receive more errors then, namely `parse error on input ‘=’` from the line `fib 0 = 1`.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
module Main where
    fib :: Integer -> Integer
    fib 0 = 1
    fib 1 = 1
    fib x = fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 2)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Well, what do you want your program to do?

Comment: I want it to print the Fibonacci  sequence.

Comment: Then you should put the code for that in `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write something like:

```
module Main where

fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib x = fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 2)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ fib 10
```

Note: your `fib` function should not be indented, it should be left aligned.

Comment: Well, you could also indent it - as long as you indent everything in `module Main` the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Because `main` should be of type `IO ()`. Something like this should work:

```
main = print $ fib 3
```

Your entire program should look like this:

```
module Main where

fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib x = fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 2)

main = print $ fib 3
```

Notice the space difference between your code and the above one in the `fib` function.

> I have tried declaring `main = do`

`main = do` just doesn't make any sense for the compiler. Remember `do` is a syntax sugar for monads. `do` is not a valid expression.